# Quiero sacar el ponderado de una base

Tags: r

```
Warning message:
`funs()` was deprecated in dplyr 0.8.0.
ℹ Please use a list of either functions or lambdas:

# Simple named list: list(mean = mean, median = median)

# Auto named with `tibble::lst()`: tibble::lst(mean, median)

# Using lambdas list(~ mean(., trim = .2), ~ median(., na.rm = TRUE))
Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was generated.
```

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: No se entiende que es lo que quieres preguntar, ¿Podrías agregar más contexto en información? por empezar el código de lo que estás haciendo. ¿Tu duda es acerca del error que muestras?

Comment: ¿cuál es la pregunta?